# Delete a certain number of characters after a string

Tags: notepad++, regex

I have a XML document where I should delete a certain number of characters after a XML tag for example:

```
<Title>0001: Title1</Title>
<Title>0002: Title2</Title>
<Title>0003: Title3</Title>
```

I should delete the 6 characters after the  tag but leave everything else as is so it would become like this:

```
<Title>Title1</Title>
<Title>Title2</Title>
<Title>Title3</Title>
```

I have searched but did not find the solution to this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In notepad++ open find replace dialog (CTRL+H)

- find what:
  `(<Title>).{6}`
- replace to
  `$1`
- make sure "regular expression" at the bottom of the form is checked
- also check "wrap around"
- press replace all

you can test the regular expression here: https://regex101.com/r/qCMHwA/1

[image]